# How can I switch perspective programmatically after starting an E4 application?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

### Scenario

I have a pure E4 application in which I want to select the initial perspective for the user depending on the user's roles. I therefore have a perspective to start with which contains one part only. In that part, I use the @PostConstruct-Method to check the user's roles and afterwards trigger the command for switching perspective:

---

Initial View

```java
@Inject
private IEclipseContext eclipseContext;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
  // checking credentials and retrieving roles come here which is pretty long
  // that's why switching perspective is a seperate method 
  // and EclipseContext is injected to instance instead of method
  this.switchPerspective(_usersInitialPerspectiveId)
}

private void switchPerspective(String pTargetPerspectiveId) {
  final ECommandService _commandService = this.eclipseContext.get(ECommandService.class);
  final EHandlerService _handlerService = this.eclipseContext.get(EHandlerService.class);

  final Map<String, Object> _commandParameter = new HashMap<>();
  _commandParameter.put(PluginIdConstants.ID_OF_PARAMETER_FOR_SWITCH_PERSPEKTIVE,
     pZielPerspektiveId);

  final ParameterizedCommand _switchPerspectiveCommand =
     _commandService.createCommand(COMMAND_ID_FOR_SWITCH_PERSPECTIVE,
        _commandParameter);
  _handlerService.executeHandler(_switchPerspectiveCommand);
}
```

---

For switching perspective from here, I use the exact same handler as from menu items configured in `Application.e4xmi`, which looks like this:

---

Perspective Switch Handler

```java
@Execute
public void execute(final MWindow pWindow,
                    final EPartService pPartService,
                    final EModelService pModelService,
                    @Named(PluginIdConstants.ID_OF_PARAMETER_FOR_SWITCH_PERSPEKTIVE)
                    final String pPerspectiveId) {

  final List<MPerspective> _perspectives =
       pModelService.findElements(pWindow, pPerspectiveId, MPerspective.class, null);
  if (!(_perspectives.isEmpty())) {
     // Show perspective for looked up id
     pPartService.switchPerspective(_perspectives.get(0));
  }
}
```

---

### The Problem

The problem is pretty simple: When using the above handler triggered by a menu item, it works as intended and switches perspective. But using the same handler by my initial view (triggering it programmatically) does not switch perspective. I debugged the code to check if the handler gets identical information in both cases and it does.

Maybe my application has not finished starting and that's why the handler has no effect, but if this is the problem, how can I check this?

Any ideas on what I maybe missed are welcome!

Comment: Are you saying `pPartService.switchPerspective` gets called in both cases?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have registered the above handler with the corresponding command in the Application.e4xmi to be executed for certain menu items with a specific perspective id as command parameter. For the same perspective id, the switch per menu item works fine but the switch levered programmatically doesn't.

Comment: I re-checked this with Eclipse IDE's debugger and in both cases I get the exactly same instance of PerspectiveImpl.

Comment: Just in case it matters: The programmatic switch is executed first. When the application is up, I click the menu item for switching from UI element.

Comment: I don't know why your appraoch doesn't work. I would suggest to either use an AddOn to select the first perspective or to do it in the LifeCycleHandler on @ProcessAdditions. The way to go would be to find the main MPerspectiveStack and then use MPerspectiveStack.setSelectedItem to set the initial perspective. That way you don't need to switch it and you don't need your "fake" perspective because it is already set correctly when the app-model is rendered.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I have figured out how to implement a LifeCycleHandler but I can't find out, how to adress my MPerspectiveStack. When I try to get this via DI to the @ProcessAdditions-Method, the method call is skipped. I tried simple injection per type, injection per @@Named with id of the PerspectiveStack and with @@Active - none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Christoph Keimel's hint I could create a working solution (thank you very much!). Here's the code that solves the problem:

```
@ProcessAdditions
private void switchPerspective(final MApplication pApplication,
                               final IApplicationContext pApplicationContext,
                               final EModelService pModelService) {

  final MWindow _window =
     (MWindow) pModelService.find(PluginIdConstants.WINDOW_ID_FOR_MAIN, pApplication);

  final String _appName = pApplicationContext.getBrandingName();
  initializeWindowTitle(_window, _appName);

  final MPerspectiveStack pPerspectiveStack =
     (MPerspectiveStack) pModelService.find(PluginIdConstants.PERSPECTIVE_STACK_ID_FOR_MAIN,
        pAnwendung);

  for (final MPerspective _perspective : pPerspectiveStack.getChildren()) {
     if (_perspektive.getElementId().equalsIgnoreCase(this.startingPerspectiveId)) {
        pPerspectiveStack.setSelectedElement(_perspective);
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

On how to register a LifeCycleHandler you can take a look at [Lars Vogel's Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html).

My main problem finding this solution was how to access the perspective stack. As the UI is not up while the method annotated with `ProcessAdditions` is running, I have to access the application model via the `MApplication` type - which is the root element of my application model. Combining the EModelService I can access all UI elements I want and manipulate them accordingly.
Injecting any UI element like the `MPerspectiveStack` or the `MWindow` leads to a skipped method as these result in null values due to not being initalized yet.